# Why are the coordinates of a MouseDown event different from a MenuDetect event?

Tags: java, events, swt

Background: I am trying to programmatically create a context menu on an SWT Table. I am doing it programmatically because I need to hide/show the menu based on the cell that was clicked, not the row item.

I was planning to use the x,y coordinates from the Event class to find the cell that was clicked on, so I am capturing both the untyped MouseDown event and the untyped MenuDetect event. I put logging messages into the event handlers so I could better see what was going on. Here's my code:

```
    tree.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
            System.out.println("Mouse down: (" + event.x + ", " + event.y + ")");
            handleMouseDown(event);

        }
    });
    tree.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener() {
        @Override
        public void handleEvent(final Event event) {
            System.out.println("Menu Detect: (" + event.x + ", " + event.y + ")");
            handleMenuDetect(event);

        }

    });
```

With the same click, I expected to see the same results, however, my output was as follows when I clicked down a column of cells:

> Mouse down: (334, 11) Menu Detect: (1270, 255)
>
> Mouse down: (331, 37) Menu Detect: (1267, 281)
>
> Mouse down: (329, 55) Menu Detect: (1265, 299)
>
> Mouse down: (324, 77) Menu Detect: (1260, 321)
>
> Mouse down: (324, 100) Menu Detect: (1260, 344)

What is going on here? Aren't they referring to the same exact point? Are they calculating the x,y from different origins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are they calculating the x,y from different origins?

Yes, they do.

The `SWT.MenuDetect` event position is the mouse position based on the whole screen, whereas the `SWT.MouseDown` event position is based on its composite.

That means that one tells you where on the screen the event occurred, whereas the other tells you where in the widget it occurred.

To make them use the same coordinate system (the widget's system), call `Control#toControl(int, int)` to map it.

```
tree.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, (e) -> {
    System.out.println(new Point(e.x, e.y));
});
tree.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, (e) -> {
    System.out.println(tree.toControl(e.x, e.y));
});
```

---

`Control#toDisplay(int, int)` will do the opposite.

---

For reference:

[`MouseEvent` Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FMouseListener.html):

> `public int x`
>
> the **widget-relative**, x coordinate of the pointer at the time the mouse button was pressed or released

[`MenuDetectEvent` Javadoc](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FMenuDetectEvent.html):

> `public int x`
>
> The **display-relative** x coordinate of the pointer at the time the context menu trigger occurred.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. I've been scratching my head over this for a while.

Comment: @chama You're welcome. I didn't think they'd be different until I tried it. The Javadoc explains it well though. Added it to my answer.